# Text() not wrapping in UIHostingController

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to render a view as an image, however, the text will not render wrapped, despite showing that way in the regular view. I've tried a frame with maxWidth of UIScreen bounds, which will work to not have the text overrun, but it condenses it, leaving one line of text cut off by "..."

How it should look:
[image: How the image of the view should look]

The image it generates:
[image]

The text that should wrap:

```
Text(data.postContent)
                        .font(.callout)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .padding(.horizontal) //, 15
                        .foregroundColor(Color(hex: 0x050505))
```

The image generation extension:

```
extension View {
var asImage: UIImage {
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
    let view = controller.view
    let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
    print(targetSize)
    view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: targetSize)
    view?.backgroundColor = .clear

    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
    format.scale = 3
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize, format: format)
    return renderer.image { _ in
        view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `maxWidth`, setting the `idealWidth` worked for me.

```
let text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt. Laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius."

Text(text)
    .font(.callout)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .frame(idealWidth: 400)
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
    .asImage
```

produced an image of size 400*167. Playground preview:

[image]

I also tried to recreate the view shown in the screenshot:

```
let view = VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    HStack(alignment: .top) {
        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill").font(.largeTitle)
        VStack {
            Text("Name")
            Text("Now").font(.caption)
        }
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
    }
    Divider()
    Text(text)
        .font(.callout)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .frame(idealWidth: 400)
}
.foregroundStyle(.white)

view.asImage
```

This produced an image of size 400x219.5. Playground preview:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a go but still got an image 1073*132, so unfortunately it didn't work. If that worked for you, I'm wondering if it might be something else causing the issue on my end.

Comment: @Flynn Indeed. It is your responsibility to show a [mcve] when posting a question.

Comment: @Flynn I edited to include a view similar to what your screenshot shows. It works for that too. I suggest asking a new question with more details.

Comment: thank you. i used your code and got the same result in a playground preview. However, all the previews with my code looked normal and correct, it was only once they were rendered as images and saved that they looked abnormal. Will work on a new question with more information.